# Asus External microphone doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS G501JW (ROG laptop) OS Windows 10, and can't get the external microphone of a headset to work. Just the built in microphone works, and it doesn't seem to recognise any other microphones. It has a dual jack that combines the headphone speakers & microphone in one.